# When I increase sidekiq concurrency, it says my pool is too small. But smaller number works

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I'm a bit new to sidekiq but I managed to get it working pretty fine recently. However, I noticed that I needed to increase my concurrency from 5 to maybe 20-25. When I edited my `sidekiq.yml` file, which shows this:

```
development:  
  :concurrency: 5
production:  
  :concurrency: 20
:queues:
  - default
```

from 5 to 25, it threw me an error stating:

> Your Redis connection pool is too small for Sidekiq to work. Your pool
>   has 20 connections but really needs to have at least 27

What exactly is this error referring to? I even changed the "production" from 20 to 30, and it still claimed that my pool has 20 connections.

If I'm increasing the concurrency, why is it *smaller* all of a sudden? Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like its complaining about the `redis` pool, not `sidekiq` connection pool

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Remove any Redis `:size` parameter you have in your Sidekiq initializer.  Sidekiq will auto-size your pools if you let it.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for this suggestion man. I really appreciate it!